# How to limit user view of system tables / views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008R2 and one of the things I am trying to do is allow users read-only access to some of the tables in one of the DBs via MS Access ODBC so that they cna build their own reports, etc (Their request).  The problem is that they can see all of the system views /tables (information_schema and merge replication stuff).  Is there anyway that I can revoke these so that all they can see are the tables /views I designate as available for selection?

Not sure what I can do to limit what they see as "available".

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them on the public role, and only give SELECT permission to the tables/views you want.

You can't stop them from seeing the system views but you can stop them viewing what those views return. If they don't have permission on the table, `sys.tables` will not return that table.